# What are the advantages of installing the newest updates for windows devices?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, automatic-update

I am here to ask what are the benefits of installing updates on windows devices besides security and slight system changes to the graphical interfaces?

Also why are the updates forced to be installed after a while of not updating your windows devices?
I am just really curious about this.

What is the advantage of the updates as sometimes it seems the updates do more damage than good such as slowing down speeds or misconstruing settings all together where options no longer exist in order to have a device run smoothly as it was per previous settings.

Also is there by any chance a cmd or shell script that would prevent updates that would run at start of PC If so I would like to use them. As it seems that my devices persist and install updates anyways at times even though I have settings set to not allowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 is akin to Windows as a Service. It is constantly evolving:  New features added (changes and additions to settings, connections, search, drawing and more). Old things terminated (Edge is no longer being developed - Chromium Edge is the new browser).

Security is very important and ever changing. Windows Defender is one of the best and for a year or so or more includes EMET (Enhanced Mitigation security now built in).

There is lots new - too much for a single thread. Each feature update has a What's New Screen that you can go through.

Because Windows is now a Service, old versions of Windows 10 (V1803 and earlier) are out of support and no longer supported.

Individuals cannot turn Windows Updates off. You must manage them and indeed, features have been added to allow you to install updates on your own schedule. Updates need not interfere with your work.

This is the new Windows design and judging by its overall success, it fits most of us.

I installed Windows 10 V2004 yesterday and it works fine.